# How to change the functionality for inserting images in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, tinymce

My webapp has functionality for uploading images, with additional information, like image title, description, tags, copyright information, etc. I use TinyMCE for editing webpages, but I don't want to allow images to be uploaded within the editor. I only want to allow the user to choose among the images already uploaded to the server.

Would it be relatively easy to change the "Insert Image"-functionality in TinyMCE to the following:

1. When the "Insert Image" button is pressed, a custom dialog pops up.
2. The contents of that dialog is a grid view of the images on the server. No upload functionality should exist here.
3. An image is selected via a radio-button.
4. When the "Insert Selected Image"-button in the dialog is pressed, instead of just the `<img>`-tag, some generated HTML is inserted at the editor cursor.

I have skimmed the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback), and I know about the `file_picker_callback`. Would I use that, and write my own javascript function to open up my own dialog? How do I control what is inserted into the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has APIs to create your own toolbar buttons that open dialogs to perform whatever task you need.

One approach is to use the TinyMCE UI:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/dialog/

The other approach is to use a URL dialog that embeds a remote web page you create.  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/urldialog/

In either case you would use TinyMCE APIs (e.g. `insertContent()`) to place the resultant HTML into the editor.